# Error al crear servicio en segundo plano android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, servicio

Que tal! Les comento: Cree un servicio en Android, pero al momento de iniciar la aplicación se cierra y quitando el servicio se quita ese problema.

Aquí inicio mi servicio:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, sservicio.class);
    startService(intent);
```

Aquí está la clase sservice:

```
public class sservicio extends Service{

    public sservicio() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio creado...");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         new CargarDatos().execute("http://www.cybertodo.mx/WebService.php?nombre=" + etNombres.getText().toString() + "&" + "longitud=" + longitud + "&" + "latitud=" + latitud + "&" + "direccion=" + direccion + ". Ciudad: " + cityName + "&" + "equipo=" + datos);


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio destruido...");
    }


}
```

Esta clase esta en el MainActivity.java. He intentado sólo mandar un log con la leyenda que el servicio se ejecutó pero aún así me cierra la app. Así puse el servicio en el AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
        android:name=".MainActivity$sservicio"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
```

Comment: Cual es el error que te manda en el log ?

Comment: Juan, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que muestra el logcat para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ese es el problema, no da error el logcat, siemplemente se cierra la aplicación al momento de intentar iniciar el servicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que `sservice` es una clase interna dentro de `MainActivity` y por lo tanto Android no logra construir una instancia.

Para solucionarlo, puedes sacar la clase `sservice` a un nuevo archivo o si prefieres definirla dentro de `MainActivity`, hazlo como clase estática:

```
public static class sservice extends Service {
    ....
}
```